# Get tweet update in miliseconds?

Tags: performance, networking, twitter, server-side, server-side-rendering

I am using twitter api with to get tweet when someone posts. It takes around 3-4 seconds to update. How can i make that faster to less then a second...

What are the recommendations regarding

1: Which server to use (Would it matter in this case)

2: Twitter API to use (Standard, Premium, Enterprise)

I would appreciate if you can recommend any other

Comment: Why you need less than a second?

Comment: @PutraPurba want to update as soon as possible..

Comment: In my experience your goal is impossible since too much bottleneck, Twitter Server, Router Hop, your Hardware Machine, your Webserver, your Application

Comment: Twitter manages those,  (bottlneck, Hop etc). Using API scheme and upgrading to fast server will do the trick.

Comment: Try it out then, if your assumption work

Comment: We are near to a second now, i think we can improve it more...

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the documentation from twitter API, rates are limited in time, therefore, you cannot make the update faster or you will run out of calls to refresh what you are trying to search. See. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting

Comment: I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-lite for streaming. It gives ping every 1-2 seconds and get data when tweeted. I don't think it violates the rate limiting. Would account activity API would be faster.
thanks!